# Unable to start a WebView from an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-webview, android-context

I'd like to start a `WebView` from my `AsyncTask` but it doesn't seem to run. This is what my `onPostExecute` method looks like:

```
  public class Viewer extends AsyncTask<URI, Integer, URI> {

      private Activity objContext = null;

      public Viewer(Activity objContext) {
        this.objContext = objContext;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(URI uriWebpage) {
          WebView wbvBrowser = new WebView(this.objContext);
          wbvBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
          wbvBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          wbvBrowser.loadUrl(uriWebpage.toString());
      }

  }
```

My task is used by two activities in my application and therefore my global `objContext` variable is of type `Activity`. If I change the type of my `objContext` variable to the name of the calling class, it works fine but then I can't instantiate my task from the other calling class. I instantiate my task like this.

```
Viewer mytask = new Viewer(this);
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: it seems like the objContext =  null or objContext is not having the valid activity reference... you have to provide proper activity ref.

Comment: It isn't that else I would have got a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. It has nothing to do with the use of `Activity` or `Context`. Both work just fine. Some URLs don't seem to load the `WebView`. I changed the URL of the `WebView` to point to a site like Google and it worked just fine. Seems like if the URL is incorrect, the `WebView` doesn't throw an exception but doesn't open up either.

Comment: I think you should create a webviewclient and take care of shouldOverrideUrlLoading, also you can monitor those sites with onPageStarted and onPageFinished

Answer (score 1):

Did you `setContentView` from original layout to webView or you have a container to put webview? otherwise I don't think webView UI appears.

Comment: I just noticed this. I fi use `WebView.loadUrl` it opens a new Browser Window.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you execute your AsyncTask

```
                    @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){              


            }
        }.execute();
```

Also need to class name

```
Viewer mytask = new Viewer(YourclassName.this);
```

// or This may Helps you

```
     private Context  mcontext;

          public Viewer(Context  objContext) {
            this.mcontext= objContext;
          }

  protected void onPostExecute(URI uriWebpage) {
          WebView wbvBrowser = new WebView(((Activity)(mcontext)));

      }
```

Comment: i think change your constructer with Context and try it again

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why this happens, but why don't you just start the built in web browser through an `Intent` in your `onPostExecute(Uri uriWebpage)`?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uriWebPage);
startActivity(intent);
```

If this solution doesn't satisfy you, then please post the error stack trace from LogCat.

Comment: Because I need to pass in some session Cookies. :(

Comment: If you're not sure about your answer, @Adam, then don't post it. The issue of the problem is that the methods in WebView can't execute in AsyncTask.